# How to get Javascript to post a form?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code:
document.forms["form_name"].submit();
It doesn't seem to work. Is there another way to submit a form using Javascript?

Comment: That's the correct method. Are you sure the `<form>` is named properly? Post your code, otherwise it's hard to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. It probably doesn't work because you have form element named "submit". Change its name and the code will work.

To confirm this is really the problem, some debug is required:

```
var sFormName = "form_name";
var oForm = document.forms[sFormName];
if (oForm) {
   if (oForm.elements["submit"]) {
      alert("form contains element named submit, can't use JS to submit it");
   }
}
else {
   alert("Form named " + sFormName + " does not exist");
}
```

Keep us updated. :)

Comment: Addendum: if you have a submit button, it's probably your form name; if you don't have a submit button, you must have one to submit the form.

Comment: @mway no, just pulled a quick test in IE and such code exactly did submit a form with no submit button whatsoever. Maybe it was true for some ancient version of IE?

Comment: That's possible - I haven't tested it for a long time, just had kept assuming it was still the case. :) Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: 90% of the time I see this question it's because there's an element with name='submit'.

Comment: @mway: no problem, I still find many times that things I knew are no longer true.. one never stop learning. :)

Comment: @James same here... one of the most common mistakes, no doubt. Hopefully that's the case here as well. :)

Answer (score -1):

If you're in Internet Explorer, there HAS to be a `<input type='submit'>` present in the form in order to work.  May just be IE7, but we've run into that problem.

To hide the button just use style='display:none;'

Comment: This is simply not correct. JS can even create blank form on the fly and submit it, let alone submit existing form.

Comment: You are absolutely right!  For some reason our IE& testing environment wouldn't allow it and I had thought it was an IE7 across-the-board issue.  Egg on my face!

Comment: No harm done, really weird that your testing environment would behave like this but I can now understand you better.. :)